# Airflow DAG success callback

Tags: airflow

Is there an elegant way to define callback for DAG succeed event?
I really don't want to set a task which will be upstream of all other tasks with on_sucess_callback.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not set a task with `on_success_callback`? I think it's "elegant" in some way. :)

Comment: because i must configure this task to be on the upstream of all of the "final" tasks in the flow, to be sure all tasks in the DAG ended successfully.
I really prefer not to do it this way, its a path for bugs to come (like forgetting  some of the "final" tasks to be parents of this task)

Comment: Only Operator has `on_success_callback` in version 1.9.0, so any solution must related with Operator. Your problem may be how to create this kind DAG easily. You can write a decorator or something else to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, the last step of your DAG is, in case of success, to call back to some other system. So I would encourage you to model your DAG exactly that way.

Why would you try to hide that part from the logic of your DAG? That's exactly what the up/downstream modeling is for. Hiding part of the DAG logic for the sake of the graph's aesthetics sounds like a bad tradeoff to me.

I would discourage you to set the callback task as downstream to *all* tasks, it should be downstream only to *final* tasks in the DAG.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know how much it helps you now, but the functionality you are looking for exists in Airflow 1.10... 
a DAG has an on_success_callback

https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.models.DAG

Answer (score 1):

Create the task and set up the upstream programmatically, that way you can't forget to add one, so long as this is done last in the file.

```
for task in dag.tasks:
    final_task.set_upstream(task)
# Only run if all the other tasks succeeded. EDIT: This is the default
final_task.trigger_rule = 'all_success'
dag.add_task(final_task)
```

Comment: Im trying to avoid doing it because this way my graph will be super ugly :(

Comment: You can try and avoid it all you like ;) but I don't know of any other way - DAGs don't have any hooks -- those live in tasks.

Comment: This will not work. From the docs: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules, 'all_success' is the default and means "trigger if all parents have succeeded".

Comment: The OP asked for "callback for DAG succeed event". That sounds like exactly this